# Necessity of UNNEST on ARRAY variable for IN() statement

Tags: sql, variables, hana

If been busy finding a solution for using an ARRAY variable to define the content of a

```
WHERE [...] IN()
```

statement in HANA SQL. It works when I `UNNEST()` the ARRAY; all other approaches failed.

I'm trying to understand the **why**. Any help is very much appreciated.

This doesn't work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE()

AS
BEGIN
    -- Define default filter values
    DECLARE variable1 NVARCHAR(255) ARRAY = ARRAY('default_value1','default_value2');

    -- Update the specified columns for matching rows
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET
        COLUMN = '1'
    WHERE
        COLUMN IN (:variable1);
END;
```

This does work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE()

AS
BEGIN
    -- Define default filter values
    DECLARE variable1 NVARCHAR(255) ARRAY = ARRAY('default_value1','default_value2');

    -- Create table for ARRAY variable(s)
    variable1_table = UNNEST(:variable1) AS ("VAR1"); 

    -- Update the specified columns for matching rows
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET
        COLUMN = '1'
    WHERE
        COLUMN IN (SELECT "VAR1" FROM :variable1_table);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to understand the why. Any help is very much appreciated.

In your first example, you use the array variable `variable1` directly in the `IN()` statement. This will not work because arrays are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause.

In your second example, you use the `UNNEST()` function to convert the array variable `variable1` to a table. Then you use `SELECT` statement to select the `VAR1` column from the table and pass it to the `IN(`) statement. It works as the `IN()` operator is now receiving a list of scalar values.

Comment: Okay; so it is just not possible to reference / use an array in the where clause. Is converting the array to a table and then selecting the column the correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: @NCFY Yes, you can create a temporary table to store the values of the array variable. The temporary table can then be used in the `WHERE IN()`.

Comment: Is this a limitation of HANA SQL? Or do other DBMS have the same constraint? I just cannot dig up specific information for that on the web... proably using incorrect search terms. Thank you for your support!

Comment: @NCFY Yes, correct. The inability to use array variables directly in `WHERE IN()` clause is a limitation of HANA SQL. Other DBMSs, such as PostgreSQL and MySQL, do allow you to use array variables directly in the `WHERE IN()` clause.

Comment: I've just checked on a local Postgres and id doesn't accept arrays either. I will investigate further but anyway thank you so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255461/discussion-between-zufar-sunagatov-and-ncfy).

Comment: @NCFY I can help you somehow else?